# SQL Join two tables, only get latest entry of second table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have these two tables:

items

```
itemname  description  belongs
A1        some_text    user1
A2        some_text    user1
A3        some_text    user1
A4        some_text    user1
A5        some_text    user1
A1        some_text    user2
B2        some_text    user2
```

movements

```
itemname  start_date  end_date    belongs
A1        2013-02-01  2014-01-12  user1
A1        2014-08-14  NULL        user1
A1        2014-10-15  2015-01-01  user1
A2        2013-08-03  2014-08-14  user1     
A2        2014-08-14  NULL        user1    
A3        2013-08-02  2014-08-20  user1
A3        2013-12-05  2014-01-07  user1
A4        2013-07-15  2014-09-13  user1
A4        2014-09-13  NULL        user1
A5        2013-07-15  2014-09-13  user1
A5        2015-03-11  2016-03-12  user1
A5        2016-03-12  2016-04-13  user1
A1        2015-08-01  2015-08-12  user2
B2        2015-08-13  2015-08-23  user2
```

I was playing around with joins and max(date) but didn't come to a working solution.

A result for user1 should looks like this:

```
itemname  description  belongs  start_date  end_date
A1        some_text    user1    2014-08-14  NULL        
A2        some_text    user1    2014-08-14  NULL       
A3        some_text    user1    2013-08-02  2014-08-20      
A4        some_text    user1    2014-09-13  NULL              
A5        some_text    user1    2016-03-12  2016-04-13
```

I need the line (movement) with the highest (latest, newest) end_date if there is no line where:

```
end_date = NULL
```

If there is a line where end_date = NULL, I need this line for that item.

Difficulty here is that sorting for max(start_date) would not work since sometimes there is a timeperiod inside another timeperiod for one item.

I hope you could understand my problem.

Greetings from germany :)

Comment: This is for `Mysql` or `Sql server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this

Find the most recent start date for each `itemname` & `belongs` combination then join the result back with max start date to get the result

```
SELECT i.itemname,i.description,i.belongs,m.start_date,m.end_date
FROM   items i
       JOIN movements m
         ON i.itemname = m.itemname
            AND i.belongs = m.belongs
       JOIN (SELECT itemname,
                    belongs,
                    Max(COALESCE(end_date, start_date)) AS max_dt,
                    Max(end_date)                       AS max_end_dat,
                    Max(start_date)                       AS max_start_dat
             FROM   movements
             GROUP  BY itemname,
                       belongs) m1
         ON m1.itemname = m.itemname
            AND m1.belongs = m.belongs
            AND ( ( m.end_date = m1.max_dt
                    AND m1.max_dt = m1.max_start_dat )
                   OR ( m1.max_dt = COALESCE(end_date, m.start_date)
                        AND m1.max_start_dat <> m1.max_dt )
                   OR ( m1.max_dt = m.start_date
                        AND m1.max_end_dat <> m1.max_dt ) )
ORDER  BY i.belongs,
          i.itemname
```

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16de3b/4)

**Update :**

```
SELECT i.itemname,
       i.description,
       i.belongs,
       m.start_date,
       m.end_date
FROM   items i
       JOIN movements m
         ON i.itemname = m.itemname
            AND i.belongs = m.belongs
       JOIN (SELECT itemname,
                    belongs,
                    Max(start_date) AS max_dat,
                    'st'            AS indi
             FROM   movements
             WHERE  end_date IS NULL
             GROUP  BY itemname,
                       belongs
             UNION ALL
             SELECT itemname,
                    belongs,
                    Max(end_date) AS max_dat,
                    'ed'
             FROM   movements m
             WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                FROM   movements m1
                                WHERE  m.itemname = m1.itemname
                                       AND m.belongs = m1.belongs
                                       AND end_date IS NULL)
             GROUP  BY itemname,
                       belongs) m1
         ON m1.itemname = m.itemname
            AND m1.belongs = m.belongs
            AND ( ( m1.max_dat = m.start_date
                    AND indi = 'st' )
                   OR ( m1.max_dat = m.end_date
                        AND indi <> 'st' ) )
ORDER  BY i.belongs,
          i.itemname
```

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16de3b/5)

This will be really easy if your `RDBMS` supports `ROW_NUMBER` window function or `APPLY` operator

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. What happens when there is a timeperiod inside another timeperiod and there is currently no unfinished movement for this item? The start_date would be higher, but the entry I am looking for would be the one with the highest end_date.

Comment: @riccy Can you add this scenario in sample data and expected result

Comment: @riccy - You mean to say to find latest movement for every item the `end_date` should be `NULL`

Comment: added this case as A3. If there is no movement for an item where end_date is NULL, I need the movement with the highest (newest) end_date. Else the entry with end_date = NULL is the one needed.

Comment: @riccy - fixed,.. check now

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aea62/1 I edited your fiddle. There are some duplicates as you can see. In your fiddle end_date is varchar, in my DB its a date field.

Comment: there still seem to be some problems as you can see in this fiddle.  for A1 and A2 the "NULL"-entry should be in the result.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df45e/1

Comment: @riccy - For `A1` this particular line `'A1', '2015-06-03 00:00:00', '2016-02-16', 'user1'` has maximum `end_date` and for `A2` this line `('A2', '2015-08-16 00:00:00', '2015-08-24', 'user1'),` has maximum `end_date` how you are expecting `NULL` values.

Comment: I see. The end_date of the previous and the start_date of the next movement are the same. But if there is a line where `end_date = NULL`, this line should always be the one in the result. For A1 this one `('A1', '2016-02-16 00:00:00', NULL, 'user1')`

Comment: @riccy - can you add a sample data that covers all these scenarios and expected result. Now am confused

Comment: Check the Sql fiddle provided by @Prdp. It's working fine.

Comment: @riccy - check the update whether it fits in all your requirement

Comment: @Prdp updatet the question and tried your update. Now it works. Thank you very much. altough it needs more than 5 seconds execution time with ca. 800 items and 4000 movements

Comment: @riccy - Glad it worked finally :D. Thats all I can come up with. Lets wait for a better answer. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

to select a record from a group of records: 
IN ALL the Methods you can join with your Items table to get extra information.

Method-1 use self join:

```
Select a.*  
from yourTable as a
left join YourTable as b
  on b.belongs = a.Belongs
 and b.Item_Name=a.Item_Name
 and b.Start_date>a.Start_Date
where b.Start_Date is null
```

Method-2, use MaxDate.

```
with MaxDate as(
Select belongs, Item_Name, Max(Start_Date) as MaxDate
from yourTable
group by belongs, Item_Number
) select * from MaxDate as a
  inner join YourTable as b 
     on b.belongs=a.belongs 
    and b.Item_Number=a.Item_Number 
    and b.Start_Date=a.MaxDate
```

Method-3, use Row_Number to flag the last record in the group

```
with LastRec as(
select *,
Row_Number() over(partition by belongs, Item_number order by Start_date desc) as RN
From yourTable
) select * from LastRec
  where rn=1
```

Method-4, use sub-query to get the last record in the group.

```
Select * from your table as a
Where a.StartDate=(Select Max(Start_Date) from yourTable as b Where b.belongs=a.belongs and b.Item_Name=a.Item_Number)
```