# Alternative to using ROW_NUMBER for better performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a small query below where it outputs a row number under the `RowNumber` column based on  partitioning the 'LegKey' column and ordering by UpdateID desc. This is so the latest updated row (UpdateID) per legkey is always number 1

```
SELECT *
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LegKey ORDER BY UpdateID DESC) AS RowNumber 
FROM Data.Crew
```

Data outputted:

```
UpdateID    LegKey  OriginalSourceTableID   UpdateReceived          RowNumber
7359        6641    11                     2016-08-22 16:35:27.487  1
7121        6641    11                     2016-08-15 00:00:47.220  2
8175        6642    11                     2016-08-22 16:35:27.487  1
7122        6642    11                     2016-08-15 00:00:47.220  2
8613        6643    11                     2016-08-22 16:35:27.487  1
7123        6643    11                     2016-08-15 00:00:47.220  2
```

The problem I have with this method is that I am getting slow performance because I assume I am using the ORDER BY.

My question is that is there an alternative way to produce a similar result but have my query run faster? I am thinking a `MAX()` may work but I didn't get the same output as before. Maybe I did the `MAX()` statement incorrectly so was wondering if this is a good alternative if somebody can provide an example on how they would write the `MAX()` statement for this example?

Thank you

Comment: What indices do you have on this table?

Comment: @Cory I have a non unique, non clustered index on the LegKey column and a clustered index on the primary key UpdateID. I don't have the rights to manipulate these indexes in the tables just to let you know

Comment: you may refer to my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933458/sql-join-two-tables-only-get-latest-entry-of-second-table/39933693#39933693 here I explained four different methods similar to your case. The MaxDate is shown in Method 4 & 2.

Comment: @AhmedSaeed If you don't mind is it ok if you apply method 4 and 2 in an answer using my example just so I 100% know how it works if you don't mind?

Comment: i added them, please check.

Comment: In my experience, ROW_NUMBER is faster than any other method. So I suggest you first test the other methods and see if anything is obviously faster (doubtful). Then if you want better performance you need to take a look at the query plan and yes you will most likely need to apply or change indexes. Is this really your full query, or are you also filtering on other things and/or filtering on the result of `ROW_NUMBER`?

Comment: Row_number() over a column which is indexed will give you best performance

Comment: You may be alright. I tried the four methods, I mentioned above, on close to 35M records DB2 table. row_number was giving the best result, next  was getting the MaxDate in cte using GROUP BY then join the cte with the actual table as shown in my answer.

Comment: @RaghuAriga idea of computing row_number is almost opposed to indexing a column. row_number is not searching - it computes something from the scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one of the following:

```
declare @Table table(UpdateID int,   LegKey int,  OriginalSourceTableID int,  UpdateReceived datetime)
```

Here using the MAX Date in subquery.

```
select * from @Table as a where a.UpdateReceived = (Select MAX(UpdateReceived) from @Table as b Where b.LegKey = a.LegKey)
```

Here you can use it in cte with group by.

```
with MaxDate as( Select LegKey, Max(UpdateReceived) as MaxDate from @Table group by LegKey ) 
select * from MaxDate as a   
inner join @Table as b 
     on b.LegKey=a.LegKey 
    and b.UpdateReceived=a.MaxDate
```

Answer (score 5):

Presumably this is the query you want to optimize:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT c.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LegKey ORDER BY UpdateID DESC) AS RowNumber 
      FROM Data.Crew c
     ) c
WHERE RowNumber = 1;
```

Try an index on `Crew(LegKey, UpdateId)`.

This index will also be used if you do:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Data.Crew c
WHERE c.UpdateId = (SELECT MAX(c2.UpdateId)
                    FROM Data.Crew c2
                    WHERE c2.LegKey = c.LegKey
                   );
```